# If $|A|=|B|$ and $|C|=|D|$ then $|A\times C|=|B\times D|$ proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have done previous questions regarding these but this one seems too abstract. I have tried to build bijective functions with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by $A*C$?

Comment: Please provide more context. What kind of entities are $A,B,C,D$? What do you mean by $\vert A\vert$?

Comment: Someone please correct my edit if they think is question is actually about countability axioms/discrete mathematics. I think this tag better suits the question.

Comment: This is not "too abstract". It is one of the most basic mathematical experiences every child makes  in the first ten years of his life.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by $A*C$ you mean $A \times C$.

Recall that $|X| = |Y|$ iff there exists a bijection between them. Therefore, it suffices to show that if there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$ and a bijection from $C$ to $D$, then there exists a bijection from $A \times C$ to $B \times D$.

**Hint:** Let $f:A \to B$, and $g:C\to D$ be bijections. Now consider $f\times g: A\times C \to B\times D$ where $(f\times g)(a,b)=(f(a),g(b))$. Can you show that this is a bijection?

Comment: The prodigal son returns!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Glad to be back.